# PyTelegramAPI передать callback_data без нажатия кнопки пользователем

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Делаю бота, который должен автоматически присылать вопросы, которые уже забиты в обработчике и вызываются по нажатию кнопки.

Как я могу "генерировать" callback_data ,который дает нажатие кнопки? Нигде в документации не могу найти ничего подобного.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
      if call.data == "ticket_1.1":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Билет 1.1')

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="  1️⃣  ", callback_data = "1.1.1")
        button_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="  2️⃣  ", callback_data = "1.1.2")
            
        keyboard.row(button_1, button_2)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ваш ответ:', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Как я могу послать данные callback_data  "ticket_1.1" без нажатия кнопки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже думал как можно возвращаться к определённому условию `call.data` дабы не "мусорить" кнопками и у меня получилось так:

```
def test(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Цифры')
    else:
        class XClass(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.message = message  # либо call.message
                self.data = 'no'
        callback_inline(XClass())
```

*Код для примера*

Comment: Простите, но я ничего не понял.

Comment: Но каким то образом это работает! СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!

Comment: создали класс в котором переопределяем `data` в `call.message` и вызываем функцию `callback_inline` передавая класс в котором сообщение содержит нужную нам `data`.

Comment: Все здорово, но в данный момент функция принимает message и не срабатывает пока нет сообщения.
Не подскажите, как сделать чтобы функция была "автономной"?
Пробовал убрать "message" из скобок, но тогда функция вообще не работает...

Comment: У вас коллбэк принимает сообщение, чтобы дальше взаимодействовать с пользователем. Как вы хотите вызывать функцию без сообщения?

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне нужно генерировать эти callback без участия пользователя. Пытаюсь реализовать это через schedule.every().day.at("9:00").do(func) . 
То есть мне нужно делать callback раз в сутки автоматически.

Comment: https://clck.ru/Re9gd пожалуйста, посмотрите этот вопрос, там я описал проблему более подробно